# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Doesn't Recognize Language Pack

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have a fresh install of CRM 2013.  When I attempt to install Rollup 3 I get this error:

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM English (United States) Language Pack is not
>   installed on this computer.

The English Language pack is installed, in fact if I try to reinstall it I get a error saying that it's already installed.  I notice if I try to repair the Language Pack it also will say it isn't installed and therefore can't be repaired.

Another post on this site installed the French pack to get around this but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: base language of your environment and language packs already installed?

Comment: Base language is English and this is a new CRM install so there are no Rollups applied.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for an answer to this question, and finally found the solution:

If you use Windows Update to installed Service Pack 1 it works around the issue where the MSI can't be used as an installer.

[Windows Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd3LC.png)